# Getting duplicates using underscore.js _.each function?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table, underscore.js

I'm doing something like this to get the JSON in an underscore template

```
 <% _.each(CList, function(d) {
    var i = 0 
      _.each(d, function(Cdata) {
          console.log(Cdata)
         var pid=JSON.stringify(Cdata["_id"]);
         if(typeof(Cdata["LOCATION"]) !== "undefined"){
       %>
       <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Check<%= i %>" onclick='myfunctioncustomer(this,id,"<%= Cdata['COMPANY'] %>"," <%= Cdata['FIRST NAME'] %>","<%= Cdata['LAST NAME'] %> ","<%= Cdata['COMPANY URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['LINKEDIN URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['PERSONAL URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['TWITTER URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['DESIGNATION'] %> ","<%= Cdata['LOCATION'] %> ","<%= Cdata['PHONE'] %> ",<%= pid %>)' value='<%= Cdata["EMAIL"]  %>' ></input></td>
       <td> <%= Cdata['COMPANY'] %> </td>
       <td> <%= Cdata['FIRST NAME'] +' ' +Cdata['LAST NAME'] %> </td>
       <td> <%= Cdata['LOCATION'] %></td>
       </tr>
      <% i++; 
      }
    })%>
  <% }); %>
```

The result gives me the json as a table with 2 rows having the same values..
I get something like this

```
 Company Name                    Name            Location
 Mercury Interactive Germany     Georg Goller    Germany
 Mercury Interactive Germany     Georg Goller    Germany
 Mercury Interactive GmbH        Gunter Kraft    Germany
 Mercury Interactive GmbH        Gunter Kraft    Germany
```

What am I doing wrong here..
I want to get rid of the duplicates

the structure of my JSON:

```
       [{"SECTOR": "", "CITY": "Missassauga", "DESIGNATION": "ASCM II", "FIRST NAME":            "Michael", "LAST NAME": "Gambarotto", "COMPANY": "Mercury Interactive Corporation", "URL": "", "PHONE": "(416) 605-7872", "LOCATION": "Canada", "ADDRESS": "5800 Explorer Drive, Suite 320Missassauga, Ontario L4W5K9Canada", "_id": {"$oid": "50b5da3dea01a32302a6a2ae"}, "EMAIL": "mgambarotto@mercury.com", "SIZE": ""}, {"SECTOR": "", "CITY": "Missassauga", "DESIGNATION": "APM Major Account Manager", "FIRST NAME": "Tim", "LAST NAME": "Healey", "COMPANY": "Mercury Interactive Corporation", "URL": "", "PHONE": "(416) 706-0171", "LOCATION": "Canada", "ADDRESS": "5800 Explorer Drive, Suite 320Missassauga, Ontario L4W5K9Canada", "_id": {"$oid": "50b5da3dea01a32302a6abfc"}, "EMAIL": "thealey@mercury.com", "SIZE": ""}, {"SECTOR": "", "CITY": "Mississauga", "DESIGNATION": "AM Manager", "FIRST NAME": "Warren", "LAST NAME": "Borthwick", "COMPANY": "Mercury Interactive Corporate", "URL": "", "PHONE": "416-419-4370", "LOCATION": "Canada", "ADDRESS": "5060 Spectrum WaySuite 400 ON L4W 5N5MississaugaCanada", "_id": {"$oid": "50b5da3dea01a32302a6adbf"}, "EMAIL": "wborthwick@mercury.com", "SIZE": ""}]
```

Comment: Are you sure the JSON-data is correct? FWIW, you don't need `var i` if you use `_.each(CList, function(d, i) { ... }`.

Comment: yup the json data is correct..If I do a console.log after the 1st _.each..it giving out proper result..but if I do after the 2nd ..I'm getting duplicate results..and var i is to have the unique id of the variables

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I just noticed the location where you increase `i`. But `_.each(d, function(Cdata, i)) {...}` should work, though.

Comment: ya,but that won't solve my current problem right ;)

Comment: got a place to download your json from? I'd have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner-most `_.each` seems to be unnecessary:

```
  <% _.each(CList, function(Cdata, i) {
    var pid=JSON.stringify(Cdata["_id"]);
    if(typeof(Cdata["LOCATION"]) !== "undefined"){
      %>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="Check<%= i %>" onclick='myfunctioncustomer(this,id,"<%= Cdata['COMPANY'] %>"," <%= Cdata['FIRST NAME'] %>","<%= Cdata['LAST NAME'] %> ","<%= Cdata['COMPANY URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['LINKEDIN URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['PERSONAL URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['TWITTER URL'] %> ","<%= Cdata['DESIGNATION'] %> ","<%= Cdata['LOCATION'] %> ","<%= Cdata['PHONE'] %> ",<%= pid %>)' value='<%= Cdata["EMAIL"]  %>' ></input></td>
      <td> <%= Cdata['COMPANY'] %> </td>
      <td> <%= Cdata['FIRST NAME'] +' ' +Cdata['LAST NAME'] %> </td>
      <td> <%= Cdata['LOCATION'] %></td>
      </tr>
      <%
    }
  }); %>
```

Comment: Hey thanks..Had to make a change , var cdata = d['attributes']; and then I was able to access the data the way you showed it..THanks for the help :)